# Linq statement for Orders reporting

Tags: c#, linq

I have orders in my database, each of which has a collection of Allowances.  An Allowance related to an Order has a ChargeIndicator to denote if it's a discount (0) or not (1).

For a time period, I need the discounts used during that time, and the sum of the orders that used each discount.

I can get the list of used discounts, but am having trouble going back to Orders to get the aggregates

```
var discounts = this.Repository.GetOrders()
            .Where(o => 
                o.AllowanceCharge.Any(ac => !ac.ChargeIndicator) &&
                o.IssueDate > DateTime.Now.AddDays(-10) &&
                o.IssueDate < DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1))
            .SelectMany(o => o.AllowanceCharge.Where(ac => !ac.ChargeIndicator))
            .Discinct()
```

Answer (score 0):

For simplicity, I'd probably just do this in two round-trips:

```
var ordersWithDiscounts = this.Repository.GetOrders()
    .Where(o => 
        o.AllowanceCharge.Any(ac => !ac.ChargeIndicator) &&
        o.IssueDate > DateTime.Now.AddDays(-10) &&
        o.IssueDate < DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1));
var sumOfOrdersWithDiscounts = ordersWithDiscounts.Sum(o => o.TotalCostOrWhatever);
var discounts = ordersWithDiscounts
    .SelectMany(o => o.AllowanceCharge.Where(ac => !ac.ChargeIndicator))
    .ToList();
```

Comment: I need the order sums /by/ discount, not all together

Comment: @MStodd: if there are two discounts on the same order, are you saying that you would get both of those discounts in the result set, and for each you would also see the (same) sum of the `AllowanceCharge` costs on the order that they're associated with?

Answer (score 0):

Simplest way would be de-normalize the relational data then apply the Aggregation on the data.

```
   // filter the allowance applied orders
   var filtered = GetOrders().Where(x => x.AllowanceCharge.Any(t => t.ChargeIndicator));

   // Flat the relations data
   var denormalized =
           from order in filtered
           join allowance in filtered.SelectMany(x => x.AllowanceCharge) on order.Id equals allowance.OrderId
           select new { order = order.Name, alName = allowance.Name };

   // groupt it

   var result = denormalized.GroupBy(info => info.alName)
               .Select(group => new
               {
                   Allowance = group.Key,
                   OrderCount = group.Count()
               });
```

Combined demoralization and groupby using Lambda expression,

```
 var result =
 filtered.Join(filtered.SelectMany(x => x.AllowanceCharge), 
               order => order.Id, allowance => allowance.OrderId,
               (order, allowance) => new { order = order.Name, allowance = allowance.Name })
         .GroupBy(record => record.allowance)
         .Select(group => new
            {
                Allowance = group.Key,
                OrderCount = group.Count()
            });
```

result -

```
{ Allowance = A, OrderCount = 3 }
{ Allowance = C, OrderCount = 1 }
{ Allowance = B, OrderCount = 1 }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you want (if you want it all in 1 query):

```
this.Repository.GetOrders()
    .Where(o => o.IssueDate > DateTime.Now.AddDays(-10) &&
                o.IssueDate < DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1))
    .SelectMany(o => o.AllowanceCharge
        .Where(ac => !ac.ChargeIndicator)
        .Select(ac => new { order = o, charge = ac}))
    .GroupBy(_ => _.charge.Id)
    .Select(grp => new
    {
        AllowanceChargeId = grp.Key,
        OrdersForThisCharge = grp.Select(_ => _.order)
    });
```